# How to properly iterate through two-dimensions array and sum all the lengths of elements?

Tags: multidimensional-array, prolog

I've encountered a problem when trying to iterate through two dimension array and summing up the lengths of all elements inside in prolog.

I've tried iterating through a simple 1D array and result was just as expected. However, difficulties appeared when I started writing the code for 2D array. Here's my code :

```
findsum(L):-
    atom_row(L, Sum),
    write(Sum).

atom_row([Head|Tail], Sum) :-
    atom_lengths(Head, Sum),
    atom_row(Tail, Sum).
atom_row([], 0).

atom_lengths([Head|Tail], Sum):-
    atom_chars(Head, CharList),
    length(CharList, ThisLenght),
    atom_lengths(Tail, Temp),
    Sum is Temp + ThisLenght,
    write(ThisLenght).
atom_lengths([], 0).
```

For example, sum of the elements in array [[aaa, bbbb], [ccccc, dddddd]] should be equal to 18. And this is what I get:

```
?- findsum([[aaa, bbbb], [ccccc, dddddd]]).
436
false.
```

The output comes from `write(ThisLength)` line after each iteration.

Comment: Can you explain how your predicate works?

Comment: atom_row - here I pass the 2D array, where I take the Head part, meaning the first array inside, and passing it to atom_lengths. Theoretically it should iterate and sum up the length of elements as it does with 1D array. If this isn't clear enough, let me know, I'll try to explain in more detail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically it helps (a lot) by splitting the problem into simpeler sub-problems. We can solve the problem, for example, with the following three steps:

1. first we concatenate the list of lists into a single one-dimension list, for example with [**`append/2`**](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=append/2);
2. next we map each atom in that list to the length of that atom, with the [**`atom_length/2`**](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=atom_length/2) predicate; and
3. finally we sum up these values, for example with [**`sum_list/2`**](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=sum_list/2).

So the main predicate looks like:

```
findsum(LL, S) :-
    append(LL, L),
    maplist(atom_length, L, NL),
    sumlist(NL, S).
```

Since [**`maplist/3`**](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=maplist/3) is a predicate defined in the [**`library(apply)`**](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=apply), we thus don't need to implement any other predicates.

> **Note**: You can see the implementions of the linked predicates by clicking on the `:-` icon.

For example:

```
?- findsum([[aaa, bbbb], [ccccc, dddddd]], N).
N = 18.
```

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation, I'm very new to this language and appreciate your help a lot.